# How to crop a UIImage without losing it's scale property?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, core-graphics, cgimage

Goal: Crop a `UIImage` (that starts with a `scale` property of 2.0)

I perform the following code:

```
let croppedCGImage = originalUIImage.cgImage!.cropping(to: cropRect)
let croppedUIImage = UIImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage!)
```

This code works, however the result, `croppedUIImage`, has an incorrect `scale` property of 1.0.

---

I've tried specifying the `scale` when creating the final image:

```
let croppedUIImage = UIImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage!, scale: 2.0, orientation: .up)
```

This yields the correct scale, but it cuts the `size` dimensions in half incorrectly.

---

What should I do here?

(*Note: the `scale` property on the UIImage is important because I later save the image with `UIImagePNGRepresentation(_ image: UIImage)` which is affected by the `scale` property)

---

---

Edit:

I got the following to work.  Unfortunately it's just substantially slower than the `CGImage` cropping function.

```
extension UIImage {
    func cropping(to rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, self.scale)

        self.draw(in: CGRect(x: -rect.origin.x, y: -rect.origin.y, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))

        let croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return croppedImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
extension UIImage {
    func imageByCropToRect(rect:CGRect, scale:Bool) -> UIImage {

        var rect = rect
        var scaleFactor: CGFloat = 1.0
        if scale  {
            scaleFactor = self.scale
            rect.origin.x *= scaleFactor
            rect.origin.y *= scaleFactor
            rect.size.width *= scaleFactor
            rect.size.height *= scaleFactor
        }

        var image: UIImage? = nil;
        if rect.size.width > 0 && rect.size.height > 0 {
            let imageRef = self.cgImage!.cropping(to: rect)
            image = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef!, scale: scaleFactor, orientation: self.imageOrientation)
        }

        return image!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this **Extension** :-

```
extension UIImage {

    func cropping(to quality: CGInterpolationQuality, rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, self.scale)

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()! as CGContext
        context.interpolationQuality = quality

        let drawRect : CGRect = CGRect(x: -rect.origin.x, y: -rect.origin.y, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)

        context.clip(to: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: rect.size.width, height: rect.size.height))

        self.draw(in: drawRect)

        let croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return croppedImage
    }
}
```

Comment: how you expect this code will crop the image from the rect's position and size ?? its not working for me

Answer (score 5):

I'm using the [ImageHelper](https://github.com/melvitax/ImageHelper) Pod for iOS and tvOS and it's working perfectly and might also fit your needs.

It brings a lot **UIImage** Extensions such as:

**Crop and Resize**

```
// Crops an image to a new rect
func crop(bounds: CGRect) -> UIImage?

// Crops an image to a centered square
func cropToSquare() -> UIImage? {

// Resizes an image
func resize(size:CGSize, contentMode: UIImageContentMode = .ScaleToFill) -> UIImage?
```

**Screen Density**

```
// To create an image that is Retina aware, use the screen scale as a multiplier for your size. You should also use this technique for padding or borders.
let width = 140 * UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
let height = 140 * UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
let image = UIImage(named: "myImage")?.resize(CGSize(width: width, height: height))
```

Also stuff like: **Image Effects**

```
// Applies a light blur effect to the image
func applyLightEffect() -> UIImage?
// Applies a extra light blur effect to the image
func applyExtraLightEffect() -> UIImage?
// Applies a dark blur effect to the image
func applyDarkEffect() -> UIImage?
// Applies a color tint to an image
func applyTintEffect(tintColor: UIColor) -> UIImage?
// Applies a blur to an image based on the specified radius, tint color saturation and mask image
func applyBlur(blurRadius:CGFloat, tintColor:UIColor?, saturationDeltaFactor:CGFloat, maskImage:UIImage? = nil) -> UIImage?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(UIImage *)getNeedImageFrom:(UIImage*)image cropRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    CGImageRef subImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, rect);
    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:subImage];
    CGImageRelease(subImage);
    return croppedImage;
}
```

calling

```
    UIImage *imageSample=image;
    CGRect rectMake1=CGRectMake(0, 0,imageSample.size.width*1/4, imageSample.size.height);
    UIImage *img1=[[JRGlobal sharedInstance] getNeedImageFrom:imageSample cropRect:rectMake1];
```